# Converting a Matlab typecast to C Code on different platforms

Tags: c, matlab, casting, typecast-operator

Initially I thought this conversion would be a peace of cake. But since it didn't worked when running on windows I have to ask for advise. This is the situation:

Given are some bytes received over can e.g. like

```
5C FE 83 10 00 00 02 29.
   ^^ ^^
```

I have to take pair number two and three and concatenate them as FE83 and interpret them as signed Number, which in this case should result in -381.

In Matlab this worked as:

```
for i = 1:length(sasBytes)
   pair23(i) = double( typecast( uint16( base2dec( strcat( hexBytes{i}{2}, hexBytes{i}{3} ), 16) ), 'int16') );
end
```

Now I'd like to have c code which does the same. I don't know where the code will run yet, so I'd rather use standard int's like int32_t. Is there anything else I have to take care off, when porting the code?

Comment: The difficulty here is taking care of byte order on different platforms. If "different platforms" is limited to intel-compatible PCs (running any of Windows, Linux or MacOS, it's the CPU that matters), then you're good to go. If you have more platforms, your MATLAB code will fail too.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Windows, Linux and MacOS would be enough.

Comment: Linux at least runs on both big- and little-endian machines. Like Cris said, it's the CPU that matters not the OS. x86 is little endian, POWER and ARM are bi-endian (but generally used in little-endian configurations these days), zarch is big endian, SPARC is complicated but mostly big-endian, etc. If you want to be conservative, I have some endian handling code at https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/blob/master/endian/endian.h you can steal.

Comment: @nemequ so I might narrower the question a bit more by talking about windows, macOS and Ubuntu all x64.

Comment: If all you're interested in is x86_64, then yes, endianness isn't a concern. macOS used to be big endian (before they switched over to Intel chips), and AFAIK Ubuntu does have big-endian variants (for POWER, and maybe ARM). Basically, stop talking about operating systems; if all you care about is x86/x86_64, say that and you should be fine.